# Textarea inside of anchor tag IE 11 issue

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a list of items which when you click, it will go to the item's detail page. However I also want add a textarea and a save button so the user can type a comment and save for that item. something like this:

[image]

below code works fine in chrome/FF, however in IE11, you have to do double click in order to type in the textarea, also the cursor will always be in the beginning instead of the end of existing text.

any idea why and how to fix it?

```js
function handleClick(e){
  console.log(e.target)
  // e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.list-item {
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com" class="list-item" >
  <button onclick="handleClick(event);"> hello 1</button>
  <textarea cols="30" rows="3" onclick="handleClick(event);" draggable="false"></textarea>
</a>
```

Comment: Remove the `onclick` from the `textarea`

Comment: that will cause clicking the textarea will navigate to another page

Comment: Simply put, you should not be doing this. `textarea` is not valid content for an `a` tag. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Interactive_content. It is not surprising your are getting inconsistent results across browsers. What are you actually meant to click on to go to Google?

Comment: the href is just sample url, it goes to the detail page of the item. if they cannot be nested, is it possible to create a listItems where clicking will go to a specific url while having textarea?

Comment: The question remains though, what are you meant to click to go to the details page? All you have in your list item are other interactive elements. Is there any text accompanying the `textarea` and `button`? What is there to click on besides those elements?

Comment: I added an image to illustrate, clicking orange area should go to the detail page of each item. save button will just do call a function. circle is a picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's break down your requirements and look at the best tag for the job

**I have a list of items** - so lets pick the best list element, probably `ul`

**Which when you click, it will go to the item's detail page.** - `a` tag

**Add a textarea and a save button so the user can type a comment and save for that item.** - We need to position these in the link, but not have the elements in the `a` tag as interactive content is not a valid child of an `a` tag.

```css
.list {
  /*Remove default list padding*/
  padding:0;
}

.list-item {
  width: 400px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: orange;
  margin: 5px;
  
  /*Make the list item the basis for positioning */
  position: relative;   
}

.list-item-link{
  /*Place the link relative to the list item*/
  position:absolute;
  display:block;
  padding:5px;
  /*Cover the list item area*/
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.list-item-note, .list-item-save {
  /*Set commom attributes for notes and link*/
  position:absolute;
  z-index:10;
  bottom: 5px;
}

/*Position elements as required*/
.list-item-save {
  right: 5px;
}

.list-item-note {
  right: 55px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="list-item">
    <a href="http://google.com" class="list-item-link">Your Image<br>Here</a>
    <button class="list-item-save">Save</button>
    <textarea  rows="3" draggable="false" class="list-item-note" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
  </li>
  <li class="list-item" class="list-item-link">
    <a href="http://google.com" class="list-item-link">Your Image<br>Here</a>
    <button class="list-item-save">Save</button>
    <textarea rows="3" draggable="false" class="list-item-note" placeholder="Notes"></textarea>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Adjust the positions and dimensions as required.